# Is it an expected behavior of UriBuilder?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

This is what I'm doing (JAX-RS 1.0, Jersey 1.11):

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
System.out.println(UriBuilder.fromPath("/").queryParam("x", "%40").build());
System.out.println(UriBuilder.fromPath("/").queryParam("x", "100%").build());
```

Expected:

```
/?x=%2540
/?x=100%25
```

But actual output is:

```
/?x=%40
/?x=100%25
```

What is going on? What is a workaround if this is how `UriBuilder` should behave?

Comment: %2540 is not correct format, your code has %40 instead of 40%, could that be issue?

Comment: URLEncoder.encode(`%40`) -> `%2540`. this is what I mean in this example.

Comment: Yes as mentioned in javadoc too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised, but this is how it works:

```
UriBuilder.fromUri("/").queryParam("x", "{value}").build(/* any text */);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that there is an extra method for building URIs from encoded Strings:

From the Javadocs:
build(): *"All '%' characters in the stringified values will be encoded. The state of the builder is unaffected"*

buildFromEncoded(): *"All % characters in the stringified values that are not followed by two hexadecimal numbers will be encoded."*

`URIBuilder.buildFromEncoded()`:
http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html#buildFromEncoded%28java.lang.Object...%29?

hope that helped

Comment: But my string is **not** encoded. It's just a string of random chars, where sometimes we may see `%` chars. And accidentally they may be followed by some digits. In this case UriBuilder decides not to encode them... what is the logic?